# What is the source of the Curie point?

Tags: electromagnetism, condensed-matter, temperature, phase-transition

I'm seriously revisiting my knowledge on magnetism, and the [Curie point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie_temperature) has been both enlightening and mystifying. I understand what it does ((ferro)magnetism disappears above it), and have a faint idea how that works. What bothers me is that if (ferro)magnetism stems from the arrangement of electrons in various orbitals (the imbalance in total electron spin), why don't a lot more materials, including basic elements, have a Curie point? What makes the very few ferromagnetic materials so unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What bothers me is that if (ferro)magnetism stems from the arrangement of electrons in various orbitals (the imbalance in total electron spin), why don't a lot more materials, including basic elements, have a Curie point? What makes the very few ferromagnetic materials so unique?

Not all materials display magnetism or paramagnetism.

> [Materials may be classified](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/solids/magpr.html) by their response to externally applied magnetic fields as diamagnetic, paramagnetic, or ferromagnetic. These magnetic responses differ greatly in strength. Diamagnetism is a property of all materials and opposes applied magnetic fields, but is very weak. Paramagnetism, when present, is stronger than diamagnetism and produces magnetization in the direction of the applied field, and proportional to the applied field. Ferromagnetic effects are very large, producing magnetizations sometimes orders of magnitude greater than the applied field and as such are much larger than either diamagnetic or paramagnetic effects.

Ferromagnetic and paramagnetic materials are characterized by the existence of magnetic domains, clusters of molecules/atoms which have a collective magnetic dipole moment because it is an energetically favorable orientation within the cluster. These can be randomly oriented cancelling each other macroscopically, in paramagnets. In ferromagnetic materials the domains are all oriented in a lattice where the dipoles add up. The [Curie point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curie_temperature) is when the kinetic energy due to temperature is large enough to turn ferromagnetic materials to paramagnetic, i.e. disoriented domains.

That is the reason why only ferromagnetic materials have a curie point, because only those lattices have oriented domains which can be dispersed when the temperature is increase above a certain point.

Comment: It's not quite what I mean. I know all of this, but from what I can see, the magnetism stems from an imbalance in the orbital arrangement of electrons by spin; if there is balance, the spins cancel each other out. But a LOT of atoms have that imbalance, so it seems every one of them should have a Curie point. But few do. What prevents all the other spin-unbalanced atoms from having a Curie point and hence the option of becoming magnetic?

Comment: paramagnetism and ferromagnetism come from cluster/domain structures, not from individual atoms and molecules.the curie point characterizes the clusters organization not the atoms/molecules

Comment: According to multiple sources I studied, the root of the magnetism is the spin of electrons, and electrons are also the source of, not surprisingly, electromagnetism. The domains are (according to what I studied) clusters of atoms or other such scale entities aligned to allow a magnetic "flow". So from what I keep hearing and reading, the source of magnetism is electrons. Which brings me back to the original question: Since electron spin is the source of magnetic properties, why can only a few materials have magnetic properties at any temperature at all (i.e. why do they have no Curie point)?

Comment: Maybe it will help you to read my answer here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/249887/why-the-properties-of-a-substance-like-color-changes-when-we-go-into-the-nano-sc/249890#249890 , on a similar question. for nanoclusters substitude magnetic domains. Quantum mechanical combinations of the basic elements, protons, neutrons electrons generate an immense spectrum of possible solid geometry shapes, with their corresponding quantum numbers and fields.

Comment: A very interesting and well-written read, but it seems to be about quantum mechanical influences on color. I can find nothing about magnetism in it. Is it the correct link?

Comment: The answer is about color, but the quantum mechanics applies to the electrons too. The electron orbitals, if the electron has an arbitray magnetic moment direction, will generally not build up in bulk matter, in clusters, a total magnetic moment, unless there is a lower energy level(s)  from a QM solution where the cluster has the magnetic moments of the electrons oriented so that a magnetic domain appears .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38478/discussion-between-henry-stone-and-anna-v).

Comment: we have different time tables, It is almost 6 in the morning where I am. I was thinking about this as I woke up. The electron orbitals will pair up and neutralize the magnetic moments as the energetically lowest level with a higher probability . The atoms which have outer electrons giving a magnetic moment , will tend thermodynamically to again pair up , north to south  when in contact unless for other, quantum mechanical reasons, it is energetically more favorable to add up. This happens with an external magnetic field in paramagnetic materials, which reverse to randomness as the

Comment: In paramagnetic materials, qm it is more favorable energetically to have clusters with a magnetic orientation, called magnetic domains, but they are oriented randomly unless an external field supplies the energy to orient them. When the field is off, thermodynamic randomness returns. In ferromagnetic materials, above the curie temperature,in an external field, they are paramagnetic. Below the curie point the lattice energetics ( qm large structures) is such that it is energetically at a lower level for the lattice  that the domain magnetic moments  stay oriented .

Comment: Let's see if I understand this a bit better, because this seems to be what I need to understand: Ferromagnetism relies on the orbital arrangement of valence electrons. In some materials, like iron, those orbitals are more free to align and create magnetic moment (or rather, keep all the atoms magnetic moment from scrambling itself into randomness). Above the Curie point, the orbitals are too "energetic" to be held in the alignment needed for magnetic moment.

Comment: And domains basically form because clusters of atoms (or molecules, I guess) with magnetic moment align one another, but unless given a large-scale "push", the domains will conflict with one another, rather than conform to any single "core" domain.

Is that anywhere near correct??

Comment: yes , the summary is correct